# while loop keeps repeating when it's not supposed to

Tags: java, while-loop

I am getting a user input and using a while loop to keep validating the input.
However, no matter what type of input I enter that is supposed to be true, it keeps returning false and repeating the loop.

This is the section of the code that uses the loop:

```
String deletelName;

System.out.println("Type patient's last name to delete");
deletelName = cin.next();   

Patient removePatient = new Patient (deletelName.toLowerCase(),null,null,null,null);

while (!bst.contains(removePatient)) {
    System.out.println("Patient's last name does not exist. Type another last name : ");
    deletelName = cin.next();
}
```

Part of the bst class:

```
public boolean contains(AnyType x)
{
    return contains(x, root);
}


private boolean contains(AnyType x, BinaryNode<AnyType> t)
{
    if (t == null)
        return false;

    int compareResult = x.compareTo(t.element);

    if(compareResult < 0)
        return contains(x, t.left);

    else if (compareResult > 0)
        return contains (x, t.right);
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: What is `bst`? You need to provide more code than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will go on forever for a very obvious reason: you are not making a new patient each time because this line

```
Patient removePatient = new Patient (deletelName.toLowerCase(),null,null,null,null);
```

is not in the while loop, and therefore it always checks with the same `Patient`. The solution is to replace this:

```
Patient removePatient = new Patient (deletelName.toLowerCase(),null,null,null,null);

while (!bst.contains(removePatient)) {
    System.out.println("Patient's last name does not exist. Type another last name : ");
    deletelName = cin.next();
}
```

With something like this:

```
Patient removePatient = new Patient (deletelName.toLowerCase(),null,null,null,null);

while (!bst.contains(removePatient)) {
    System.out.println("Patient's last name does not exist. Type another last name : ");
    deletelName = cin.next();
    removePatient = new Patient (deletelName.toLowerCase(),null,null,null,null);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

removePatient isn't changing, only deletelName. So in order to fix your problem, add in `removePatient = new Patient (deletelName.toLowerCase(),null,null,null,null);` at the end of your loop.

Comment: I was writing the same thing in a much longer way, and you answered in that time span :D I think we're both correct, so +1 from me :)